# Does Wrapper Class records Allow DML Operations ?Thank You

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I am using a wrapper class to fetch records from various objects , now i would like to know  can delete records of different objects using wrapper class ?
Thank You!!!

MY apex Page :--

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClass" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="w" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Book Title">
                {!w.bookTitle}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Merchandise Price ">
                {!w.merchandisePrice}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Candidate Country">
                {!w.candidateCountry}
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Delete Record">
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRecord}" >
               **<!--   <apex:param name = "id" value="{!w.id}"/>  -->**
                </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

When I am passing the parameter it is showing error ,

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Save error: Unknown property
>   'wrapperClass.myWrapper.id'   myWrapperPageDemo.page  /Library Management
>   System/src/pages  line 0  Force.com save problem

Controller error :

> Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type Save error: sObject type
>   'myWrapper' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom
>   object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please
>   reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate
>   names.    wrapperClass.cls    /Library Management System/src/classes  line
>   69    Force.com save problem

```
public class wrapperClass {

// Decide what you have to show on the page 
        public class myWrapper{
        public double merchandisePrice{get;set;} // get from Merchandise__c object
        public String bookTitle{get;set;}      //  get from Book__c object
        public String candidateCountry{get;set;}// get from Candidate__c object
        }

  // NOw think from where you will get the data like Objects and fetch the required data from those objects

   public void fetchDetails(){
   List<Merchandise__c> merList = [Select Price__c from Merchandise__c limit 4 ];
   List< Book__c> bookList = [Select title__c from Book__c limit 4];
   List<Candidate__c> candList = [Select  Country__c from Candidate__c limit 4];
   wrapperClass(merList ,bookList, candList);
   }

  // Create list of wrapper Class as public as it needs to be shown on page
  public list<myWrapper> wrapperList{get;set;}

  public void wrapperClass(List<Merchandise__c> mList , List< Book__c> bList ,    List<Candidate__c> cList ){
                        wrapperList = new list<myWrapper>();
                        myWrapper wrap;

                        Integer counter=mList.size();
                        // gets the total number of records we have to display 

                        for (Integer i =0;i<counter;i++){

                        wrap = new myWrapper();
                        Integer c=0; 
                        if (c==i)
                        for (Merchandise__c m :mList){
                                if (c==i){
                                        wrap.merchandisePrice =m.price__c;
                                    }
                                        c=c+1;
                        }
                        c=0;
                        for (Book__c b:bList){
                                if (c==i){
                        wrap.bookTitle = b.title__c;
                                }
                                c=c+1;
                        }

                c=0;                    
                        for(Candidate__c cand :cList ){
                        if (c==i){
                                wrap.candidateCountry = cand.Country__c;
                        }
                        c=c+1;
                        }
                        wrapperList.add(wrap);
                        }       
  }
  public wrapperClass(){
                fetchDetails();
                }

                //For deletion of record I have to recieve the id of the record , 
                // therefore , i am passing the id by <apex:param> component

                public Integer id{get;set;} 
                public PageReference deleteRecord(){
                String wrapperId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');   
                    if (wrapperId!=''){
                **myWrapper  wrapDelete = [Select id from myWrapper where id=:wrapperId ];**
                  delete  wrapDelete;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you can delete in a wrapper class.

Comment: @mast0r can u please look at the code and assist me in doing so !!! Thanking you in Advance!!

Comment: Can't you see that `myWrapper` is NOT an sObject? You can't read it from the database...